# websocket и работа с $_SESSION

Tags: php, сессия, websocket

Подскажите, есть ли какой-то способ или возможность работать с сессиями на сервере после получения сообщения от клиента? Я так понимаю можно передать id сессии, который хранится в куке, но вот как потом с этим делом работать, не совсем представляю.

---

Простой пример:
Есть некоторые операции, которые могут выполнять только определенные группы пользователей, у которых есть определенное значение в $_SESSION['groupId']. Нужно как-то проверить, если ли у пользователя, который отправил запрос-сообщение в вебсокет, права на отправку таких запросов. Если есть - вебсокет возвращает какое-то сообщение или производит какие-то действия с базой данных.

Или нужен какой-то другой вариант, как организовать безопасную работу с вебсокетом, при определенной системе ролей пользователей в проекте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала нужно понимать что из себя представляет механизм сессий:

- PHP передает клиенту (браузеру) куку со спец. именем (по умолчанию PHPSESSID)
- Браузер как и положено передает все куки обратно серверу с каждым запросом
- PHP зная имя спец. параметра в куке, который является именем сессии, находит физический файл сессии в папке, в которой хранятся файлы сессий PHP (определяется настройками в php.ini)

Сам файл сессии представляет из себя сериализованный ассоциативный массив.

И да, это всё касается конечно же HTTP-протокола.

Руководствуясь данной информацией несложно сделать вывод, что если хотите при общении с веб-сокетом использовать данные сессии клиента, то необходимо по веб-сокету с клиента передавать идентификатор сессии из куки самостоятельно, и самостоятельно находить файл сессии в файловой системе вашего сервера.
По безопасности, думаю, что это не менее безопасно как и передача сессии по http и никакие дополнительные токено-генерилки делать не нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Работа с websockets средствами php на сервере по определению не очень хорошо. И про $_SESSION - забудьте сразу. 
Авторизацию socket соединения нужно проводить отдельно, например по токену. Можно сгенерить его из email юзера + соли. По этому токену при инициализации определяете пользователя и его права и храните эти данные в списке подписчиков websocket обработчика. При подаче команды - сверяете есть ли у данного подписчика нужные права.

Comment: А какие средства лучше тогда использовать для организации постоянного соединения? Знаю, про Node.js, которым тыкают везде, но он пригоден далеко не для всех проектов.

Comment: NodeJS действительно лучший вариант, что есть. Для PHP я в паре проектов использовал https://github.com/nekudo/php-websocket (вроде) , помогает в освоении технологии на раннем этапе, но в итоге портировал всё на Node, код получается проще и изящней. Связь с основным проектом можно делать или через json API  или через БД подключив библиотеку mysqljs

Comment: По моему опыту, нужно отталкиваться от задачи. Конечно, про вебсокеты на PHP легенд не слагают, но у кого-то это работает) Вот хорошая статья по вебсокетам PHP на [Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/209864/)